# Volley NoConnection: Protocol Exception: Unexpected Status Line(Error msg: Method not allowed. Must be one of GET

Tags: java, android

This happens if I do network calls consecutively. And it may happen to any of api's I have. I'm using GET request, cache false. Checked in browser its working fine there. Looking at server side, they are sending response with status 200. when it reach app, im getting error response.(Does cache has anything with it)

```
import android.content.Context;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

/**
 * Created by surendra on 18/6/17.
 */

public class VolleySingleton {

    private static VolleySingleton mInstance;

    private Context mContext;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private VolleySingleton(Context context) {
        mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
        mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();
    }


    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
            // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }



    public static synchronized VolleySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new VolleySingleton(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }
}



// code to call singleton

  StringRequest request = new StringRequest(method, url, listener,errorListener){


            @Override
            protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                return super.getBody();
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                return getMyHeaders();
            }
        };
        request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(timeout, 2,2));
        request.setShouldCache(false);
        VolleySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(request);
```

Comment: Post your code, how you are making request?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure Internet permission is there in manifest. It did't look like its happening because of setShouldCache().it just disable the cache for a particular url. See this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/) ,it might help you to understand Volley library.

Comment: permission given.